# Finding action-angle variables

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, phase-space, integrable-systems

Given a 1 d.o.f Hamiltonian $H(q,p)$ what is the general procedure for finding action angle variables $(I, \theta)$?

I have read the Wikipedia page on [action angle variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action-angle_coordinates) and [canonical transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) but have difficulty applying the general methods to specific problems. Can someone explain the method to me using a simple general example?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/386062/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In local coordinates the canonical transformation to action angle coordinates $(q,p)\rightarrow (Q,P)$ can be related by,
\begin{equation}
\boxed{P_i=\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint p_idq^i \ \ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \ Q^i=\frac{\partial }{\partial P_i}\int p_idq^i}
\end{equation}
**For Example:**

Consider the one dimensional [harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator) with the following Hamiltonian $H=\frac 1{2m}\big[p^2+m^2\omega ^2q^2\big]$. Rearrange this for $p$ and take the hypersurface $H=E$. 
\begin{equation}
p=\pm \sqrt{2mE-m^2\omega ^2q^2}
\end{equation}
Then use the above equation to compute $P$. 
\begin{equation}
P=\frac{1}{2\pi }\oint \sqrt{2mE-m^2\omega ^2q^2}dq
\end{equation}
The integral is now over $0$ to $2\pi$ which is easier to handle. This works out as, 
\begin{equation}
\frac {1}{2\pi}\oint ^{2\pi}_{0}\cos^2Q\ dQ\cdot \frac {2E}{\omega}
=\frac{E}{\omega}
\end{equation}
Therefore we have used the quoted formula to compute the action variable for the harmonic oscillator.

Comment: I have a small question. Why is the limit taken from 0 to $2\pi$?

Comment: This could become a truly great answer if you expanded on the subtleties of the integrations, noting that one is a countour integral whereas the other is an indefinite integral.

Comment: The limits are for one complete period. It has to be taken as the turning points if the motion is a closed loop on the phase space. If on the other hand the system has energy greater than the binding energy, then the period can be scaled to $2\pi$.