# How are action variables linked to first integrals of a Hamiltonian?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

Suppose I have an integrable Hamiltonian system $H(q_{1}, p_{1},..., q_{n}, p_{n})$, with first integrals $F_{1} = H, F_{2},..., F_{n}$. Excluding certain singular level sets (i.e. separatrices), one may convert to action-angle variables $(I, \varphi)$, (at least locally in the complement of singular level sets), and write $H(I)$.

My question is, how exactly are actions $I$ related to first integrals $F$? We know that generally, $I_{i} =I_{i}(F_{1},..., F_{n})$,  for $i=1,..,n$, i.e. $I$'s are functions of $F$'s.  Can we say anything further about the specific form of these functions?

More specifically, for what type of Hamiltonians can we take $I_{i} = F_{i}$?

Edit. My motivation comes from the following Hamiltonian: $$H = H(q_{1}, p_{1},..., q_{j}, p_{j}, F_{k}(q_{j+1}, p_{j+1}), q_{j+2}, p_{j+2},..., q_{n}, p_{n})$$

where $F_{k}$ is one of the first integrals, that depends only on $(q_{j+1}, p_{j+1})$. Can one, in this case, take $I_{k} = F_{k}$?

As a further motivation, consider a one-dimensional oscillator $H = p^{2} + q^{2}$; here one may simply take $I = H$ (up to an adjustment of a constant factor). How does this generalise to the type of Hamiltonian given above?

Comment: Comment to the post (v3): The last appearance of the word [_first integrals_](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55861/2451) seems to play the role of a separation function.

Comment: 1. If the separation functions $F_1, \ldots, F_n$ are functionally independent, then they are automatically Poisson commuting and constants of motion, cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/291845/2451). 2. The interplay between constants of motion and action variables is considered in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/386852/2451).