# Confusion about the action variable definition

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, integrable-systems

Suppose we have an integrable system consisting of a $2n$-dimensional phase space $M$ together with $n$ independent functions $f_{1\leq j \leq n }$ in involution. Suppose the level set

$$M_f = \{ (p,q)\in M | f_k(p,q)= c_k \}, \text{where} \ c_k = \text{const.},$$

is compact so that it is diffeomorphic to a torus. The action variables are then defined as the circle integrals over the $n$ independent circles on the torus:

$$ I_k = \oint_{C_k} \sum_k p_k dq_k . $$

The apparent question is then, why do we bother to define a new set of variables, i.e. the action variables in this way? Why not just take the $f$'s as the action variable? Anyway, they are already in involution.

Answer (score 0):

The circle integrals/action variables $I_k$ are e.g. used in the construction of the [angle variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action-angle_coordinates), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/386062/2451) related Phys.SE post.